# Why I am getting error while fetching data from my backened in nodejs?

Tags: axios, mern

**Frontened Code-**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const data = {userId: item.userId};
        const fetchDetails = async (data) => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/user/getNameAvatar',data);
                console.log(res);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        fetchDetails(data);
    }, []);
```

**
Backened Code-**

```
export const getUserNameAvatar = async(req,res) => {
    try {
        const {userId} = req.body;
        console.log(userId);
        const user = await User.findById(userId);
        return res.status(200).json({userName:user.userName,avatarUrl:user.avatarUrl});
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'some internal error'});
    }
};
```

Error:- while I am consoling the userId in backened it's shows **undefined**

I have also tried by adding data using params but is also showing error on that one also...

Comment: Do you have a JSON middleware enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Axios won't attach a body to a GET request. You're actually passing the data to the `config` object, and it won't get sent to the server. Instead, you could pass the userId as a query parameter on the frontend side:

```js
const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/user/getNameAvatar?userId=${userId}`);
```

And take it from there in the backend side:

```js
export const getUserNameAvatar = async(req,res) => {
    try {
        const userId = req.query.userId; // Here
        console.log(userId);
        const user = await User.findById(userId);
        return res.status(200).json({userName:user.userName,avatarUrl:user.avatarUrl});
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'some internal error'});
    }
};
```

Comment: But if my sending the userId in the Body in JSON format using POSTMAN it is working fine. Can you tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: @PiyushKumar as I wrote in the first sentence - Axios doesn't attach a body to GET requests

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of body parser on the backend side. [refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MA4C.png). Though I have used it directly on loginRoute, you can mount it directly in main file.
Eg : app.use(jsonParser)